# Ansible Playbook with include_tasks

Tags: ansible, vmware

I have an Ansible playbook called `main.yml` that builds a Windows VM using an OVF template. It then configures the VM using variables that I pass. Typical Ansible stuff.

What I would like to do is have another task inside the `main.yml` run at the end that configures a couple things on the VM (`configureserver.yml`). I pass `"{{ vmName }}"` as a variable in the `main.yml`, and want the 2nd playbook (`configureserver.yml)` to run against that `"{{ vmName }}" variable.

Main.yml (removed some of the customization to shorten this post)

```
- name: Deploy Virtual Machine from an OVF template in content library
  community.vmware.vmware_content_deploy_ovf_template:
    name: "{{ vmName }}"
    hostname: "{{ vcenterName }}"
    username: "{{ vmwareUser }}"
    password: "{{ vmwarePassword }}"
    template: "{{ templateName }}"


- name: Configure the VM
  community.vmware.vmware_guest:
    name: "{{ vmName }}"
    hostname: "{{ vcenterName }}"
    username: "{{ vmwareUser }}"
    password: "{{ vmwarePassword }}"
    datacenter: "{{ datacenterName }}"
    cluster: "{{ clusterName }}"
    datastore: "{{ datastoreclusterName }}"

# THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD

- name: Configure the D Drive
  include_tasks:
      file: configureserver.yml
```

configureserver.yml

```
- hosts: "{{ vmName }}"
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - passwords.yml
    - vars.test.yml
  vars:
    - ansible_connection: ssh
    - ansible_shell_type: cmd
    - ansible_become_method: runas
    - ansible_become_user: System
```

In the code above, I want to run a separate task in a separate yml that will configure the server. I want to run the `configureserver.yml` playbook against the `"{{ vmName }}"` variable as the inventory or host.

Glad to provide more details if needed.

Comment: is your question how to pass a variable to include_tasks? If so, can you update this question with that?

Comment: Sorry about that. Im having an issue passing the `"{{ vmName }}"` as the variable to the `hosts` in the second playbook. 

Id like to run the `configureserver.yml` playbook against the `"{{ vmName }}"` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I changed the `include_tasks` to `include_playbook` and that did the trick